# MVC 5 Form not posting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get a login in page with Identity to work and for some reason it's not doing a POST, it's doing a GET instead. My login is not working so i put a breakpoint on both the GET and POST of the LOGIN action of my AccountController and I see it go to the GET and not to the POST where I need it to go. Looking at the code for the Login.cshtml it looks like it should be posting and it's pointing to the correct action in the controller.

Basically what's happening right now is that when I view the page, enter a username/password, and click the button it will just refresh back to a new Login page. This is basically just using the out of the box login page/controller on an new MVC site with individual accounts set.

Anyone see and issue and/or have a suggestion on how to get it to do a POST?

Login.cshtml

```
@using Site.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                    </p>*@
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

AccountController

```
 // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

ViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
After seeing one of the answers below what I decided to do was create a new simple MVC project with Accounts. I then copied the form piece from that login page and replaced mine. Now it works.

I'm using .Net 4.5.2 in the project. This is what I used. Not sure what the problem was initially but at least it's working now.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

Comment: How do you know that the POST action is not being hit? Did you put a breakpoint in it? Did you inspect the network traffic in the browser to see exactly what requests are being sent?

Comment: by default get method is being called use form.post too

Comment: Yes, I set a break point on the POST. When that didn't hit I put it on the GET as well. Then it hit.

Comment: You'd get this behavior if allowanonymous wasn't set correctly on the post method.

Comment: The code is posted above. Is the AllowAnnonymous set incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Try change;

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

### instead:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
```

change is: FormMethod and routeobject.

Comment: No, you are wrong. There's no such overload. The OP is using the correct method as can be seen from the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Object%29

Comment: Yes, there is an overload like this. Your example is first asp.net mvc application that build from Visual Studio built-in. Maybe you can intercept your submit operation with Postman ? Which results are you getting from it ?

Comment: Could you please point to the overload you are referring to on the official MSDN documentation? Here's the list to pick from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx As you can see there's no overload like `BeginForm(string, string, FormMethod, object, object)` which is what you seem to be suggesting in your answer.

Comment: I just created new mvc project and all fields like yours. Now I changed the login.cshtml form submit code like this : `@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))`  then i tried an it worked. just try it. Btw my framework version is .net 4.6.1 documentation is : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Object%29

Comment: The overload you are pointing to is `BeginForm(string, string, FormMethod, object)` which is not what you showed in your answer. In your answer you refered to some non-existent `BeginForm(string, string, FormMethod, object, object)` method.

Comment: OK, sorry i got you, missed last parameter. Maybe your model state is always coming false? And always runing `return View()` statement on the Post action ?

Comment: I updated my question above with what I did to get it to work. Thanks for the comments, it actually got me to an answer.